# VBA : Protect whole sheet and leave range unprotected

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on Excel and would like to know if there is a way, within a script, to protect a sheet entirely but leave a certain range totally unprotected (the range here is ("B2", "C32")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Format, unlock the cells you want to allow updating (they are all locked by default), then activate sheet protection, with or without password. For VBA learning, use the recorder.

Comment: Hi, is it possible within a script?